# Is there a way to find the first smaller value than a variable in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that searches for the smallest value less than `k = 6`. It returns `2`.
How can I modify it to get the first value smaller than 6, by respecting the order of the list? For the below example, the output should be `3`.

```
# Initializing list
test_list = [3, 2, 4, 7, 5, 10, 18]

# Initializing k
k = 6

min_val = min(i for i in test_list if i < k)
print(str(min_val))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in test_list:
    if i < 6:
        print(i)
        break
```

Why are you using `min()`?, it can be as simple as this.

Comment: coz I just try a test , actually I'm not working with this list I'm working with a  file which contains strings and values , so I wanna return the first smallest value of an x, that's all bro , thaaank you duuude

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this:

```py
test_list = [3, 2, 4, 7, 5, 10, 18]
# Initializing k
k = 6
filterd_list = [i for i in test_list if i < k]
print(f"{filtered_list[0]}")
```